# Hubot Slack: How to send message includes channel link?

Tags: coffeescript, slack, hubot

I wrote following hubot script to send remind.

```
OUT_CHANNEL = "remind"

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /test/, (res) ->
    res.send "set reminder. I tell you at ##{OUT_CHANNEL} after this."
...
```

This script sends below messages.

```
"set reminder. I tell you at #remind after this."
```

But This case, the part of #remind is not link.

how to embed channel link in hubot message like human send?

Environment is below:
hubot 2.19.0
hubot-slack 3.4.2
slack-client 1.4.0
Slack.app 2.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Slack to show a link to a channel the correct syntax is:

```
<#C12345678[|text]>
```

Where `#C12345678` is the ID of the public channel, and `text` can be any text (and is optional). So `<#C12345678>` will work too.

I am not familiar with the coffeesecript syntax, so please add any script related character encoded (e.g. `##` for `#`) as necessary.

Please note that this will only work for public channel, but not for private Slack channel.

You can read more about how to correctly link items in Slack messages in the excellent [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users)n.

Comment: thanks but It could not works. it shows plain text like <#C5XXXXJVB[|remind]>

Comment: The `[` are to say it's optional. Can you try `<#C5XXXXJVB|remind>` ?

Comment: Thank you!  `<#C5XXXXJVB|remind>` works what I want.

Comment: sorry I'm beginner of stackoverflow. I want to save the answer in this question, but cannot check comment. and I wrote the answer. But if you are able to wrote the answer, I want to delete my answer and check your answer. What's the right way?

Comment: @rootpetit: Just mark the correct answer by clicking on the "checkmark"